# корректная работа значков BottomNavigation

Tags: java, android

при создании активити происходит выбор какой фрагмент отобразить на основе Extras в intent, и при выборе не первого фрагмента, а второго или третьего у BottomNavigation все равно выбранным остается первый значок соответствующий первому фрагменту. Помогите пожалуйста как их синхронизировать?[image: На картинке показано отображение 2 фрагмента, и как вы видите у Bottom Navigation выделен значок 1 фрагмента]

Код как создаётся фрагмент:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            if (currentPageId == item.getItemId()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                currentPageId = item.getItemId();
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.full_info:
                        selectedFragment = new FullFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.detailed_info:
                        selectedFragment = new DetailedFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.manage_scan:
                        selectedFragment = new ConnectionFragment();
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

                return true;
            }
        }
    };
```

Код как выбирается какой фрагмент поставить:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null && whichFragment.equals("may_you_please_set_detailed_fragment")) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            DetailedFragment fragment = new DetailedFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        } else {
            if(savedInstanceState == null) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ConnectionFragment fragment = new ConnectionFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При старте программы вам кроме выбора фрагмента так же нужно программно отмечать и пункт нижнего меню, делается это так:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
```

дальше в функции `onCreate()`:

```
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(myNavigationItemListener);
```

и при выборе нужного фрагмента отмечайте нужный пункт меню:

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id);
```

и тут пишете программный выбор пункта меню:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null && whichFragment.equals("may_you_please_set_detailed_fragment")) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            DetailedFragment fragment = new DetailedFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id); // тут отмечайте нужный вам пункт меню по id 
        } else {
            if(savedInstanceState == null) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ConnectionFragment fragment = new ConnectionFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
                bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id); // тут отмечайте нужный вам пункт меню по id
            }
        }
```

Comment: к сожалению после того как я сделал как вы предлагаете, изменилось только то, что перестали обновляться фрагменты)

Comment: если переходить через нажатия - отмечаются

Comment: проблема состоит в том, что всегда отмечается первый пункт меню независимо от того какой фрагмент появляется при загрузке активити, сейчас попробую, минуточку, не подскажите как сделать так, чтобы в комментарии появлялось это "@ДанилСычев"?

Comment: посмотрите обновленный ответ

Comment: Да, это то, что было нужно, всё заработало, огромное спасибо за подробный ответ и помощь!!